# How to call a c++ function that returns a class from c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, adapter, dllimport

I have functions written in c++ and I want to use the functions in another c# project. it worked well for a couple of functions but in the functions in which I returned a class, it doesent seem to work (I have the same class in both sides).
I created an adapter that returns a class called CProfile :

```
class CProfile
{
    public double timeStamp;
    public int dimL, dimR;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CProfile getProfileAdapter(int nInt)
{
    std::cout << "get profile" << std::endl;
    Profile profile=R->getProfile(nInt);
    CProfile cProfile;
    std::cout << "get time stamp" << std::endl;
    cProfile.timeStamp=profile.timeStamp;
    std::cout << "get dimL" << std::endl;
    cProfile.dimL=profile.leftProfile.size();
    std::cout << "get dimR" << std::endl;
    cProfile.dimR=profile.rightProfile.size();
    return cProfile;
}
```

and in the c# project I call this function like this :

```
 class CProfile
 {
     public double timeStamp;
     public int dimL, dimR;
 };

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

     CProfile c = new CProfile();
     c = getProfileAdapter(0);

 }

 [DllImport("c:\\Ran\\pmcppdllran.dll")]
 static extern CProfile getProfileAdapter(int nInt);
```

Comment: I would use a struct here, classes are a different animal since they are reference types. Its not so simple to marshal classes like that, but structs are easier.

Comment: C# and C++ classes and objects are implemented very differently. For example, C# objects are garbage-collected whereas C++ objects need to be explicitly deleted (unless you take other measures). If you really want to do classes and objects, I believe you will have to go either the C++/CLI route, or COM.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! I used structs instead of classes and it worked. but unfortunately in the other classes there are arrays, and I cant initialize an array inside a struct in c#.

Comment: @Ransar arrays of what? You might be able to do something with `StructLayout`

Comment: I have arrays of doubles in both classes.

Comment: The C++ `class` is just the same as a C++ `struct`, but with different default visibility. The C++ `class` needs to be marshalled as a C# `struct`, in this instance. Arrays can be marshalled readily enough. You have to do a bit more thinking.